# How do I check a list of c++/cli ref items for contains?

Tags: c#, c++-cli, equals, contains

A c++/cli ref class `DataEntity` implements Equals and HashCode. I can check the behavior of the `Equals` implementation via:

```
entity1.Equals(entity2);
```

(C# source) and it works correctly. 
If I now have a list of such DataEntities and I call `Contains(entity)` on that list, the Equals method never gets called.

What is the reason for, and how can I use the List.Contains(...) method correcty?

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the method Contains(...) calls Equals(...)

---

**Example:**

C++/CLI source:

```
public ref class DataEntity : System::Object
{
public:
    DataEntity(System::String^ name, 
        System::String^ val) 
        : m_csName(name),
        m_csValue(val) {}

    System::String^ GetName() { return m_csName; }
    System::String^ GetValue() { return m_csValue; }
    virtual bool Equals(Object^ obj) new {
        if(!obj){
            return false;
        }
        DataEntity^ other = (DataEntity^)obj;
        if(other){
            if(m_csName->Equals(other->m_csName) &&
                m_csValue->Equals(other->m_csValue)){
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
    virtual int GetHashCode() new {
        const int iPrime = 17;
        long iResult = 1;
        iResult = iPrime * iResult + m_csName->GetHashCode();
        iResult = iPrime * iResult + m_csValue->GetHashCode();
        return iPrime;
    }

private:
    System::String^ m_csName;       
    System::String^ m_csValue;
};
```

C# source:

```
DataEntity entity1 = new DataEntity("Name", "Value");
DataEntity entity2 = new DataEntity("Name", "Value");
Console.WriteLine("Entities 1&2 are Equal: " + entity1.Equals(entity2));

List<DataEntity> entities = new List<DataEntity>();
entities.Add(entity2);
Console.WriteLine("ListContains_Entity2: " + entities.Contains(entity2));
```

Output:

```
Entities 1&2 are Equal: True
ListContains_Entity2: False
```

Comment: Please provide a [simple self-contained compilable example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Wilbert Example added.

Comment: That's "ref class DataEntity" or colloquially "the DataEntity ref class", not "ref DataEntity class". `ref class` is one of the [(spaced) keywords](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hsutter/archive/2003/11/23/53519.aspx). A `ref class` and a `class` are distinct things; One is not a variant of the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   virtual int GetHashCode() new
```

There's your mistake.  You wrote a *replacement* of GetHashCode that shadows the Object::GetHashCode.  It doesn't *override* the method.  The List::Contains method knows beans about your replacement, it still calls Object::GetHashCode().  Where it will quickly end since all of these objects have a different hash code that eliminates the need to continue looking for equality.  You made the same mistake with Equals().

You **must** use the `override` keyword here:

```
virtual bool Equals(Object^ obj) override {
    // etc...
}

virtual int GetHashCode() override {
    // etc...
}
```

Be careful with using the *new* keyword like that.  It only serves one purpose, it suppresses a strong warning from the compiler when it thinks you are doing it wrong by hiding the base method.  That warning is accurate 90% of the time, 99% when the base method is virtual.

Comment: Your solution works fine for `list.Contains(...)`, but I have the same issue if I want to check two lists for equality: `list1.Equals(list2)`, even if I use the `override` keyword (for both C++/CLI methods, Equals and GetHashCode) as you suggested. What is the reason for?

Comment: Sure, the List class doesn't implement Equals(), it is much too expensive.  It inherits Object::Equals(), you'll only ever get *true* if list1 and list2 are identical objects.  No idea what you might have overridden, use the Ask Question button.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you've implemented an overload like this:

```
public bool Equals(DataEntity entity)
```

That will *not* be called by `Contains`. However, if you override the `Equals(object)` method declared in `System.Object`, that *will* be called.

That would explain both symptoms, because

```
entity1.Equals(entity2)
```

will use your overload. To check whether it works when using the method declared in `Object`, just use:

```
entity1.Equals((object) entity2)
```

... and I suspect you'll find your method isn't being called.

Comment: Thank your for your reply. I think the question wasn't clear enough. Hence I added an example to it. Equals works fine for me, but Contains doesn't work properly since it doesn't call the Equals method from the C++/CLI class